# Nightwatch - grabbing a nested button in a nav-bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium, selector

I'm currently doing some automated tests for my website, in which I need to grab hold of a button using css selectors by using the `click()` method in `Nightwatch` with Selenium server.

My navbar looks like this:

> main nav -> nav navbar-nav navbar-right -> dropdown (two of these - I need the second) -> dropdown-toggle (this is the button that needs to be pressed).

I've tried doing it by having the selectors going through, as well as using nth-child's to grab the second, but it's proving to be tricky.  My current code looks like:

```
browser
    .waitForElementVisible('body')  
    .click("ul.nav.navbar-right > li.dropdown:last > a")
```

Comment: What is a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:last` is not a valid CSS selector, you probably meant to use [`:last-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp).

Side note: Since you know that you (always) want to click the second dropdown, I personally prefer being as verbose as possible in my tests, so I would also consider using [`:nth-child(2)`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly.  I was playing around with different selectors - weirdly enough using `:last` worked perfectly when using headless tests but not using Nightwatch.  I also prefer to use `:nth-child()` purely because of the flexibility it gives.